# EF Core Add-Migration and Update-Database Fails Silently (Build succeeded)

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, asp.net-core, .net-core

I have recently started working with EF again after many years and this might be a dumb question.

When I run `Add-Migration` (and `Update-Database`) from the Package Manager Console and there are no errors in my entities, it works fine. However, if I make a mistake, `Add-Migration` fails as expected, **but** it doesn't give me any feedback as to what went wrong and the build succeeds every time. **How do I get the EF CLI to show me the error**?

In the case of `Update-Database` failing silently, I added code to do automatic migrations and then I can see the exception when the application runs, but I can never see the error through the CLI.

I am using a corporate laptop with a lot of restrictions, so I assume it either has something to do with that, or I am just have something configured wrong, or I'm doing something wrong.

This is what it looks like when it fails...

```
PM> Add-Migration SomeMigration
Build started...
Build succeeded.
PM>
```

This is what it looks like when it succeeds

```
PM> Add-Migration SomeMigration
Build started...
Build succeeded.
To undo this action, use Remove-Migration.
Add-Migration : Value does not fall within the expected range.
At line:1 char:1
+ Add-Migration SomeMigration
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (:) [Add-Migration], ArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.ArgumentException,Add-Migration
 
PM>
```

I find it interesting, that when it shows an error, it actually worked!

**UPDATE**

Selecting the correct project is **NOT** the problem. Please don't suggest that. As stated above, migrations can be created successfully if the code has no errors. The issue is showing the errors when errors exist.

Comment: there should be a -verbose option somewhere (syntax varies from CLI vs Package Manager Console)

Comment: Good suggestion, but yes, I have used `-verbose` and that doesn't help at all. Not errors are displayed.

Comment: also note that you can get syntax help using (I think) the `Get-Help` cmdlet. (`Get-Help Add-Migration` or something like that; sry can't remember for sure since I use `dotnet ef` at the command line and not the package manager console.)

Comment: I have also used the `dotnet ef` commands with the same-ish results. Other command windows pop up as it's trying to build and create the migration. The window that pops up just disappears with no error. And, no error shows in the original command window.

Comment: hmm, at command-line verbose output should show the build output itself. I don't know about popup windows, that is not something that happens for me. I would make sure you have the most recent tools (most recent is 7.0.13 I think). you could also try obvious wrong options to see if you at least get normal error messages. `dotnet ef asdf` in the wrong directory should say no project was found, etc.

Answer (score -1):

Did you choose the right project to be run? That is, the project that has pointed to the database in the appsettings.json file.
From run toolbar, you must select the main project to run, in the Package Manager section, you must select the project that contains EF.

The solution must not have any build errors before being used for migration

Comment: Yes, as I mentioned, it succeeds when I don't have an error in the code. I am just not able to always understand where the issue is in the code because I get no feedback.

Comment: However, one important bit of info might be that the entities are in a separate project than the repository project. I have to use the repository project, where the db context is, for the migrations to work.

Comment: do not important! in package manager default project combobox select your entity project and from vs main run project select the project that has connectionstring data.

Comment: I think the point is being missed here. Selecting the correct project is NOT the problem. I have the correct project selected. When the entities don't have errors, I can use `Add-Migration` with no problems. It's when the CLI should be showing an error, it does not.

Comment: Your target project 'x' doesn't match your migrations assembly 'y'. Either change your target project or change your migrations assembly.
Change your migrations assembly by using DbContextOptionsBuilder. E.g. options.UseSqlServer(connection, b => b.MigrationsAssembly("yy")). By default, the migrations assembly is the assembly containing the DbContext.
Change your target project to the migrations project by using the Package Manager Console's Default project drop-down list, or by executing "dotnet ef" from the directory containing the migrations project.

let me show what's the error!

Comment: another error is!
Unable to create an object of type 'DbContext'. For the different patterns supported at design time, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=851728

two error fixed by select correct projects

Comment: Oh man! For this, the entire solution should not have an error.

Comment: Please stop suggesting to change the project. Again, that is NOT the problem. I can create and run migrations just fine when no code errors exist.

Comment: the same error to another Microsoft product for .net, so uninstall unnecessary.net framework and update to latest version. maybe solved the problem.